# Ruby regex - single match across lines

Tags: ruby, regex, multiline

My plan:

1. Get everything after `Send to:` and the end of that line.
2. Get everything between `Attn:` and the end of that line.

NOTE: The `Attn` line could be optional. In that case, just return the first line.

The string looks like this:

```
str = <<-MSG
Registry of Credit Recommendations
American Council on Education
One Dupont Circle, NW
Washington, D.C. 20036
Transcript Print Date: 10/03/2018
Sent By:Send To: American University
4400 Massachusetts Avenue, NW
Washington, DC 20016-8001
Attn: Undergraduate Admissions
Jonathan A Jones
30 People's Court
Second Address Line
Third Address Line
Augusta, GA 30909
MSG
```

Expected return value must be:

```
American University
Attn: Undergraduate Admissions
```

**Notice the "Attn: " part must be included, not just the content of it. **

Here is my approach, which only works for the Attn part, but I have no idea how to get the "American University" part.

```
regex = /Attn:([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+/
```

Test: http://rubular.com/r/Px4ru6WrAg

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try with [`(?<=(?:Attn:[\s*]|Send To:[\s*])).*$`](http://rubular.com/r/Px4ru6WrAg).

Comment: @SebastianPalma when I run your solution str.scan(regex) it outputs ["American University", "Undergraduate Admissions"] and I'm expecting just one substring: ["American University/n Attn: Undergraduate Admissions"] also notice the "Attn:" part is included.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

`(?<=Send To:).*|Attn:.*`

- `(?<=Send To:)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is `Send To:`. Then match one or more times any character
- `|` or
- `Attn:.+` Match Attn: followed by one or more times any characer

[Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/sxCWUbAWuc)

Comment: Sorry, the output of your solution is very different than the expected output.

Comment: Your values are in the first capturing group.

Comment: is it possible to just have one capture group instead of two?

Comment: In this regex there is only one capturing group which is `([^\r\n]+)` If you don't want any capturing group you could use the regex @revo suggested.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I see that Revo solution excludes the "Attn: " title.

Comment: Then remove `\K` to have it. The point was `[^\r\n]+` is literally equal to `.+` when `m` flag in ruby is not on: `(?:Attn|Send To):.+` @victorhazbun

Comment: @victorhazbun So you mean like `Send To:\K.*|Attn:.*` [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/HDh1LVKwXy)

Comment: @Thefourthbird on Rubular the solution `regex = /Send To:\K.*|Attn:.*/` looks good but then I run it on IRB and the output was: `["Send To: American University", "Attn: Undergraduate Admissions"]`, notice "Send To:" must not be included, just it's content. Ruby 2.5.1

Comment: @victorhazbun Ah I see, this should work `(?<=Send To:).*|Attn:.*` [Test](https://repl.it/repls/RotatingInternationalAssociate)

Comment: @revo is it possible to make this regex `/(?<=Send To:).*|Attn:.*/` return one group instead of two?

Comment: @victorhazbun You can't concatenate two individual matches into one capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't have to use a regular expression.

```
str.each_line.
    map do |line|
      case
      when line.include?("Send To: ")
        line[line.index("Send To: ") + "Send To: ".size..-2]
      when line.include?("Attn: ")
        line[line.index("Attn: ")..-2]
      else
        nil
      end
    end.compact
      #=> ["American University", "Attn: Undergraduate Admissions"]
```

`-2` excludes the newline character that ends each line.